# Unable to scroll view pager in nested scroll view layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have view pager and swipe refresh view under nested scroll view.It is working fine but problem is view pager is not scrolling only recycler view is scrolling below view pager.I want to scroll layout.

This is my xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearHome"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

As seen in screenshot view pager is set fixed on top and recycler view is scrolling below. I want to scroll view pager also some one please let me know how can I achieve desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: viewPager is not scrolling means..your nestedScrollView is not scrolling..? am i right?

Comment: Yes Prachi exactly..

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll the whole layout all we need to wrap nested scroll view under swipe refresh layout and this will scroll the whole layout.

**Updated layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context=".Home"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/linearHome"
   android:paddingBottom="16dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="12dp"
   android:paddingRight="12dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/nobook"
    android:src="@drawable/nobook"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/refresh">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

      </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Replace your recyclerView with,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here,

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

will manage the rest of things.

Comment: Nothing changes after adding it.

Comment: @Digvijay you don't have to put the recyclerview in the nestedlayout. Try to put it outside the nestedlayout

Comment: How can I put recycler view  out of Nested scroll view as nested scroll view height is match parent.

Comment: making it wrap_content

Comment: After putting swipe refresh layout out of nested scroll view and changing nested scroll view height to wrap_content view pager is not scrolling it is fixed on top and only recycler view is scrolling.

Comment: have you added: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
to your nested scrollview too?

Comment: Yeah I have added scroll behavior to both nested scroll view and swipe refresh layout and put swipe refresh layout out of nested scroll view but no luck so far.

Comment: I got that we need to wrap nested scroll view under swipe refresh layout and now whole layout is scrolling perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for help bro I have posted an answer please go through it and accept it as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Just **add** `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your **NestedScrollView** to scroll its child layouts and also **remove** `android:scrollbars="none"` from **NestedScrollView**.

Comment: Is there any string value I need to set in strind.xml

Comment: Will get back to u after trying it.